# Can I do this in Modulo arithmetic?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, coprime

The question says:

**Find n for $(5n+6)8^{2n} \equiv 0 (mod 13)$ where $n$ is a normal number.**

The book simply solved it by saying that since $8^{2n}$ and 13 are coprime(I dunno how though) then

$5n+6 = 0 (mod 13)$

And we find in the end $n = 4 (mod 13)$

But I didn't solve it this way because I didn't know how we can know if $8^{2n}$ is coprime with 13, I didn't it this way, I found it by

$(5n+6)8^{2n} \equiv 0 (mod 13)$

Which means $(5n+6)(-1)^{n} = 0(mod 13)$

We try for $n =2k+1$:

$(5(2k + 1) 6)(-1) = 0(mod13)$

Which means after calculating and all

$k = 8 (mod 13)$

We put k in n and we find

$n = 2(13 k + 8) + 1$ which is $n = 26k + 17$

Then for $n = 2k$(So -1 becomes 1 because it's an even number):

Same steps and we find $n = 26k + 4$

Now the thing I mostly ask about is, can I do this:

$n = 26k + 17$ which is $n = 13(2k) + 17$ and by defining $a = 2k$ then we write it $n = 13a + 17$ and since 13 is bigger than 17 we write it this way:

$n = 13a + 4$

And we do the same thing for $n = 26 k + 4$ which means $n = 13(2k) + 4$ and by putting $a = 2k$ then we can write it $n = 13a + 4$

And since we found the two values the same then we can say that n has a single value which is $n = 13a + 4$ which can be written

$n = 4 (mod 13)$ which is exactly as the book found it.

I have two questions:

1. How the book found that $8^{2n}$ and $13$ are coprime even though we don't know the exact value of n?
2. Can I solve it my way? I have doubts about it and I think it's wrong because I couldn't wrap my head around how I found $26k + 17 and 26k + 4$ in the first time(And they are clearly not equal) but then when I made them to $13a + 17$(Which is $13a + 4$) and $13a + 4$ they were clearly equal...how is that possible in math? I thought that if something is clearly not equal then no matter what you do and how you simplify it then you can't make them have the same form or make them equal.

Can anyone answer these two questions, please?

Comment: "since $8^{2}$ and 13 are coprime(I dunno how though)" ummm... because $13$ is prime and $8$ is even.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Wouldn't the power of 2n affect it, though?

Comment: In your case you have to be careful with how you handle and describe $n$ and show that you hit all the instances of $13k+4$ - but yes you can do it that way. However it is very basic that $13$ and $8^n$ have no prime factors in common - what could they possibly be?

Comment: @TechnoKnight:  Of course not.  Write it out:  $\underbrace{8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdots}_{2 n}$.  When would you ever get a factor of $13$????

Comment: @MarkBennet But why I found them not to be equal first but then I found them equal in the end, how is that possible?

Comment: Two numbers are coprime if and only if they have no prime factors in common. Since $8=2^3$ all powers of $8$ are powers of $2$ and so cannot have a common factor with any odd number.

Comment: When you argue that $26k+17$ and $26k+4$ are not equal, you should realise that the $k$ in the two cases is different and also that you have done a lot of $\bmod 13$ adjustment on the way that practically guarantees they won't be *equal*, only *equivalent mod $13$*.

Comment: @Joffan Okay I understood that but is my way correct in the end of the day, though?

Comment: Your version works (so is correct), but you are simply not taking advantage of the fact that if you have $ab \equiv 0 \bmod p$ with $p$ prime, you must have either $a\equiv 0 \bmod p$ or $b\equiv 0 \bmod p$ (or both). And you know that $8^m$ is never divisible by $13$ - you even make this clear by your step of $8^{2n} \equiv (-1)^n \bmod 13$..

Comment: The integer solutions $(n,m)$  of n and it's $\mod13$ result in $15$-digit math are

$$
(0,6)\quad 
(1,2)\quad 
(2,3)\quad 
(3,5)\quad 
(4,0)\quad 
(5,8)\quad 
(6,10)\quad $$